# How to skip specific element in SimpleXML

Tags: java, simple-framework, visitor-pattern

I am using SimpleXML framework for deserializing backend answers. I made some assumptions about elements. Some elements do not meet these requirements. For example, I expect an element to have childs `<ID>` and `<face>`. If my user is not allowed to see a specific element, I might get an answer like this:

```
<list>
  <voucher type="hiddenobject">
    <face>foo</face>
  </voucher>
  <voucher type="object">
    <ID>42</ID>
    <face>bar</face>
  </voucher>
</list>
```

Which gives me a ValueRequiredException for the following deserialization class:

```
@Root
class Voucher {
  @Element(name="ID")
  private String id;

  @Element
  private String face;
}
```

I would like to ignore these objects with type `hiddenobject`. I learned about the `VisitorStrategy` and implemented a simple `Visitor` like so:

```
private static final class HiddenObjectVisitor implements Visitor {

    @Override
    public void read(Type type, NodeMap<InputNode> node) throws Exception {
        String nodeType = node.getNode().getAttribute("type").getValue();

        if (nodeType != null && nodeType.equals("hiddenobject")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "skipping node " + node);
            node.getNode().skip();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Type type, NodeMap<OutputNode> node) throws Exception {
        // stub
    }
}
```

and added this `Visitor` to a `VisitorStrategy`

```
VisitorStrategy strategy = new VisitorStrategy(new HiddenObjectVisitor());
```

expecting that this would skip nodes during deserialization. I do get log entries stating that the node would be skipped. Anyway, the `VisitorStrategy` seems to keep parsing the node to be skipped, resulting in a `ValueRequiredException`.

How can I ignore nodes having a given attribute? Is it possible to use `VisitorStrategy` for this task?

Comment: is it advisable to have class **ActiveVoucher** extends **Voucher**, where *ActiveVoucher* would have required attributes, while *Voucher* wont have required attributes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably combine the approach suggested by `Raniz` with your `HiddenObjectVisitor`.  Annotate `id` with `required=false` to avoid the `ValueRequiredException`, and then use your `HiddenObjectVisitor` to skip some of the `Voucher` objects during deserialization.

Based on the XML that you have shown, `id` is not required in the XML file, and that is what `required=false` indicates.  But you imply that `id` is required in your deserialized objects, so you can discard the invalid objects at the time of deserialization.

Answer (score 4):

One thing you can do is to mark ID as [optional](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#optional) and include the type attribute so you can filter after deserialisation.

```
@Root
class Voucher {
  @Attribute
  private String type;

  @Element(name="ID", required=false)
  private String id;

  @Element
  private String face;
}
```

You can then filter the vouchers after they have been deserialised:

```
// Deserialise the XML
List<Voucher> vouchers = ...;

// Filter the list of vouchers
List<Voucher> nonHiddenVouchers = new ArrayList<>();
for (Voucher voucher : vouchers) {
    if (!"hiddenobject".equals(voucher.getType())) {
        nonHiddenVouchers.add(voucher);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already thought about that. I would like to keep my assumptions about valid objects. For example, I use ID in .equals(), where it would be bad to have a null ID.